# How to access one entity object per 2 http requests in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have restfull Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 web application. I need the following when editing some entry on UI:

1. Open entry on UI (send request with entry ID, load with Hibernate entity object by this ID, send it back to UI as JSON).
2. Make some changes on UI and click save.
3. Receive JSON on server side and update existing entity object (from step 1)

How can I do this (one entity object per 2 http requests)?

Comment: Just load the entity again. Why complicate matters?

Comment: Boris the Spider, because I want to provide concurrency

Comment: How does that impact on anything? What is the issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resending the json object with id again for update is the best idea. because you dont need to edit the particular attribute in the entity object which was changed in the ui. Receiving the complete json and update method of hibernate makes the edit process easier.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to work on this scenario is to use session.

On Step 1 add entity to request session and on step 3 get entity from request session and then update entity after that remove entity from request session.